# angularjs ui-route when page is Refresh its comming to its default page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here i'm using angularjs when i refresh my browser its comming to default page not staying on same page

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('Contact', {
        templateUrl: '../Homepages/HomeScripting/HomeContact.html',
        controller: 'abc'
    })
             .state('root', {
                 url: '/',
                 template: '<b>This is Home</b>'
             })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')
```

Comment: `.state('Contact'` is missing `url` part

Comment: even though no result